# Can SHOUTcast station access be restricted?

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

I'm considering SHOUTcast for a solution where I need to restrict listeners. I haven't used SHOUTcast before. It would be installed on a Windows server.

I want to require the listeners to log in before being able to stream a station from the server. Once logged in I then want to be able to limit them to one station only across all the (Winamp?) clients they have installed.

Is this possible? If not, is there a similar product that can do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOUTcast does not offer authentication capability.  Icecast does.

For limiting users to one stream at a time, see my answer on your other question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541842/362536